# Cheating expert bosses

Tags: terraria

I know that in a normal world I can spawn blue slimes on top of me, so I take 1 damage to render me invulnerable to any other attack. With a campfire and a heart lantern nearby and standing in honey it's possible to tank the moon lord in a normal world for an infinite amount of time.

Does this also work in expert mode? Seems one hell of an easy way to beat any boss. The only problem would be killing Skeletron as you cannot get the mechanic before entering the dungeon.

Comment: Note that in 1.3.0.6 the Moonlord was changed to make that not work. There is nothing on that page to imply that any of the other bosses was changed however, so I believe that this should work. I have not tested it though.

Comment: I saw that too but I haven't experienced any change. I decided to try my old way of beating the Moonlord and it still works. I do notice I take more hits but spawning 3 slimes and killing them grants enough random heart drops to keep me alive. I suppose i have to test it myself.

Answer (score 1):

It probably does (I haven't tested). Here's why I think that:

1. The blue slimes are to maximize invincibility frames. In expert mode they get stronger in hardmode and post-plantera, so you do need better armor for it to work.
2. If you do this with an ironskin potion and a regeneration potion should make you practically invincible to the slimes, with a campfire, lantern, heart statue, and honey.
   Yeah. It should work.